# python rdma "Hello World"

Tags: python, infiniband, rdma

This program is my first attempt at Infiniband programming. I am using this library:

https://github.com/jgunthorpe/python-rdma

I am probably doing very funny things wrong. I am just trying to send a sequence of bytes "Hello, World" to a multicast address.

```
import sys
import errno
import unittest
import mmap

import rdma
import rdma.vmad
import rdma.IBA as IBA
import rdma.ibverbs as ibv
import rdma.satransactor
import rdma.path
import rdma.vtools

from rdma.tools import clock_monotonic
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


class umad_self_test():
    umad = None;
    tid = 0;

    def __init__(self):
        self.umad = None
        self.tid = 0

        self.setUp()

    def setUp(self):
        self.end_port = rdma.get_end_port();
        self.ctx = rdma.get_verbs(self.end_port);

        #print self.end_port, self.ctx

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ctx.close();
        self.ctx = None;    

    def test_basic(self):
        print self.ctx.query_port();
        print self.ctx.query_device();

        pd = self.ctx.pd();
        print pd,repr(pd)

        cq = self.ctx.cq(100);
        print cq,repr(cq)

        try:
            cq.resize(200);
        except rdma.SysError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.ENOSYS:
                raise

        comp = self.ctx.comp_channel()
        print comp,repr(comp)

        qp = pd.qp(ibv.IBV_QPT_UD, 100, cq, 100, cq)
        print qp,repr(qp)
        print qp.query(0xFFFF)
        mpath = rdma.path.IBPath(self.ctx. end_port, DLID=0xC000,
                                 DGID=IBA.GID("ff02::1"))
        qp.attach_mcast(mpath)
        qp.detach_mcast(mpath)

        buf = mmap.mmap(-1,4096);

        mr = pd.mr(buf,ibv.IBV_ACCESS_LOCAL_WRITE|ibv.IBV_ACCESS_REMOTE_WRITE);
        print mr,repr(mr)
        print "MR",mr.addr,mr.length,mr.lkey,mr.rkey

        ah = pd.ah(self.end_port.sa_path);
        print ah,repr(ah)

        srq = pd.srq();
        print srq,repr(srq)
        print srq.query();
        srq.modify(100);

        pool = rdma.vtools.BufferPool(pd,count=100,size=1024);
        pool.post_recvs(qp,50);

        buf_idx = pool.pop();
        pool.copy_to("Hello, World!", buf_idx);
        qp.post_send(pool.make_send_wr(buf_idx,pool.size, mpath));

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        umst = umad_self_test()
        umst.test_basic()
        umst.tearDown()
```

This is the output I get:

```
[idf@node2 python]$ python myverbs.py 
port_attr(state=4, max_mtu=5, active_mtu=5, gid_tbl_len=128L, port_cap_flags=39389290L, max_msg_sz=1073741824L, bad_pkey_cntr=0L, qkey_viol_cntr=0L, pkey_tbl_len=128L, lid=1L, sm_lid=1L, lmc=0L, max_vl_num=3L, sm_sl=0L, subnet_timeout=18L, init_type_reply=0L, active_width=2L, active_speed=4L, phys_state=5L)
device_attr(fw_ver='2.7.200', node_guid=GUID('0025:90ff:ff1a:0070'), sys_image_guid=GUID('0025:90ff:ff1a:0073'), max_mr_size=18446744073709551615L, page_size_cap=4294966784L, vendor_id=713L, vendor_part_id=26428L, hw_ver=176L, max_qp=163704L, max_qp_wr=16351L, device_cap_flags=8166518L, max_sge=32L, max_sge_rd=0L, max_cq=65408L, max_cqe=4194303L, max_mr=524272L, max_pd=32764L, max_qp_rd_atom=16L, max_ee_rd_atom=0L, max_res_rd_atom=2619264L, max_qp_init_rd_atom=128L, max_ee_init_rd_atom=0L, atomic_cap=1, max_ee=0L, max_rdd=0L, max_mw=0L, max_raw_ipv6_qp=0L, max_raw_ethy_qp=0L, max_mcast_grp=8192L, max_mcast_qp_attach=248L, max_total_mcast_qp_attach=2031616L, max_ah=0L, max_fmr=0L, max_map_per_fmr=8191L, max_srq=65472L, max_srq_wr=16383L, max_srq_sge=31L, max_pkeys=128L, local_ca_ack_delay=15L, phys_port_cnt=1L)
pd:0:mlx4_0 PD(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),0x0)
cq:0:mlx4_0 CQ(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),0x0)
comp_channel:5:mlx4_0 CompChannel(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),5)
qp:193:pd:0:mlx4_0 QP(PD(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),0x0),0x0,193,qp_type=IBV_QPT_UD(4))
(<rdma.tools.qp_attr object at 0x7f0d29aa24d0>, <rdma.tools.qp_init_attr object at 0x7f0d29aa2550>)
mr:0:pd:0:mlx4_0 MR(PD(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),0x0),0x0,0x7f0d34377000,4096,lkey=0xb0042102,rkey=0xb0042102)
MR 139694687350784 4096 2953060610 2953060610
ah:6E616269 AH(0x6e616269)
srq:0:pd:0:mlx4_0 SRQ(PD(Context('mlx4_0',fd=3),0x0),0x0)
srq_attr(max_wr=127L, max_sge=1L, srq_limit=0L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myverbs.py", line 97, in <module>
    umst.test_basic()
  File "myverbs.py", line 92, in test_basic
    qp.post_send(pool.make_send_wr(buf_idx,pool.size, mpath));
  File "ibverbs.pyx", line 1461, in rdma.ibverbs.QP.post_send
TypeError: an integer is required
[idf@node2 python]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the direct problem is that you are not initializing the dqpn (destination QP number) of the path object. According to the [IBPath docstring](https://github.com/jgunthorpe/python-rdma/blob/dcdea5ee9982ae98f5a27020ae3def3afd4f418f/rdma/path.py#L76) a destination QP number is required when using unconnected QPs.

Comment: What does this line do? qp = pd.qp(ibv.IBV_QPT_UD, 100, cq, 100, cq)

Comment: I'll have to look at the documentation for the specific arguments, but it basically creates a new UD (unconnected datagram) QP.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that I am already providing a dqpn through the above statement?

Comment: No, with UD QPs, a different destination QP number can be provided in each outgoing message, so it belongs in the path object you are using to create your address handle.
I think there are examples in the python-rdma package under `tests/verbs.py`